# How can I conditionally intercept I/O done via os.path, shutil and subprocess modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, proxy

I'm working on a Python 2.7 project doing a fair amount of I/O; processes are launched via the `subprocess` module, directories are created via `os.makedirs`, files are copied via `shutil.copy2` and more.

Now I'd like to a "dry run" mode, i.e. the program doesn't actually do any I/O. Is there an easy way to do this, knowing that basically all my I/O is done using the three modules os, shutil and subprocess?

Two approaches I considered so far:

1. Write wrapper functions for all the things I'd like to silence, e.g. `mymakedirs` which just forwards to `os.makedirs`. All wrapper functions check a global flag and do nothing if requested. Unfortunately this means not only writing a lot of wrapper functions but also touching a lot of existing code.
2. Write proxy modules like `myshutil` which consider a global flag and depending on that either do `from shutil import *`, or it provides stubs. The only downsides to this I can see - how can I easily tell what stubs to write (can I see what functions are called in a module?), and I'd need to do a slight modification to all client code so that e.g. `import shutil` is changed to `import myshutil`.

The second idea seems the best to me so far, but I wonder: is there another, even nicer technique to proxy an existing module with as little modification to existing code as possible?

Comment: Is anything launched from `subprocess` running a system shell or non-python executable. If so, you have a potentially larger problem although `/dev/null` may be your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solution 1, you don't need to rewrite your code: you can monkeypatch os to intercept the calls:

```
>>> def mymkdir(*args):
...         print "mkdir", args
... 
>>> os.mkdir = mymkdir # monkey patching os
>>> os.mkdir("toto")
mkdir ('toto',)
```

You probably can even switch the entire module something like `os = myos`. Sorry I don't have time now to figure out a concrete solution.